# Reversing an array of characters in C++ using pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, c-strings

So the program is supposed to use a loop to count the total size of the array of characters that contains "Hello World!", return that count as an int, and then call a function that uses pointers to start at the beginning and end of the array to swap the characters until the null point " " in between the words. I have largely figured out the code, but it won't compile correctly and won't display or won't complete the swap, I keep getting the following error:
"LNK1168    cannot open Lab06.exe for writing"
How can I fix this?

```
#include "targetver.h"
#include <iomanip>
#include <array>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //int to hold size of array
    int count = 0;
    // declare a c-string to reverse
    char myString[] = "Hello world!";
    //print array as is
    cout << myString << endl;
    //find size of the array


    // call the reverser function
    reverser(myString, count);

    // output the result
    cout << myString << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

int findSize(char myString[], int count)
{

    count = (unsigned)strlen(myString);
    cout << "The size of the Array is: " << count << endl;
    return count;

}


void reverser(char myString[], int count)
{
    findSize(myString, count);
    char *strPtr;
    char *endPtr;
    endPtr =& myString[count];
    strPtr = myString;

    for (int x = 0; x <= count; x++)
    {
        strPtr++;
        *strPtr = myString[x];
        endPtr--;
        *endPtr = myString[count--];
        *strPtr = *endPtr;
        cout << strPtr << endl;
        cout << endPtr << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: first by showing the error message(s) u are getting

Comment: `endPtr =& myString[count];` looks like UB to me.

Comment: -drescherjm, UB?
-pm100, sorry. Edited post with error.

Comment: ***"LNK1168 cannot open Lab06.exe for writing*** Means your last build is likely still running. Or your antivirus is blocking you.

Comment: does it actually compile. Did you try it under a debugger. Look at the value of count as you step thorugh

Comment: @drescherjm - more likely the last run.

Comment: open task manager. look for all instances of lab06.exe and kill them

Comment: -drescherjm, completely closed Visual studio 2015 and reopened solution, still the same error, along with 'Access Denied' on build errors

Comment: UB= Undefined Behavior. You may be stepping out of bounds for your char arrays. I am not exactly sure.

Comment: @drescherjm why UB, its perfectly valid

Comment: Have you tried compiling with `cl.exe` on the command line to avoid any caching VS might be doing?

Comment: I was worried about the combination of that could possibly lead to accessing out of bounds of the array.

Comment: @drescherjm it would be UB if he passed in count as intended but in fact he passes in 0

Comment: couldn't find instance of visual studio running, shut down and restarted just in case, still the same error. Something about the code looks odd, but I can't for the life of me figure out how

Comment: Reboot your PC.

Comment: didnt say anhting about VS running - i said look for lab06 running

Comment: @pm100. I see now.

Comment: i did shut down and restart PC, same error

Comment: If you are still getting "LNK1168 cannot open Lab06.exe for writing" after rebooting disable your antivirus especially if you use avast.

Comment: The ***LNK1168 cannot open Lab06.exe for writing*** error has nothing to do with the code. It means Visual Studio does not have permission to write the executable or the executable already exists and is running or your AV is blocking your executable. The first can be caused by running Visual Studio as an admin then trying to run as a normal user.

Comment: disabled AVG, program build worked, console came up, but code itself must be wrong somewhere as it does not do what it is supposed to. prints out the original array correctly and the count size, but then prints out "Hllo world!", "HHHllo world!" and "HHllo world!" on three separate lines...Gives pop up saying
 "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'myString' was corrupted."

Comment: The code has several bugs. Use your debugger to step line by line through the code looking at the variables. @pm100 already mentioned that count is wrong (its actually 0) when you call `reverser(myString, count);` in main().

Comment: ***.Gives pop up saying "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'myString' was corrupted*** This is likely an out of bounds access to a stack variable. Step up the callstack to your code when this happens to see the line of code that causes that.

Comment: @drescherjm How do I do that? I edited the code to call findSize() inside reverser() to try and remedy count issue, no luck

Comment: You are passing count by value in `findSize()`. `findSize()` returns the count but your code throws it away. If you are going to return the count no need to pass count. If you don't want to return count change the parameter to pass by reference instead of by value. This is not the only error. You will have to use your debugger. Single step through the code looking at the variables. F11 will single step.

Answer (score 2):

OK lets start at the top

findsize returns the size, but you are ignoring it. You try to pass in count as an argument and hope to update count in findsize. This isnt how C works. So first do

```
int findSize(char myString[])
{

    int count = strlen(myString);
    cout << "The size of the Array is: " << count << endl;
    return count;
}
```

now when you call findsize you must remember the result.

```
int count = findsize(myString);
```

This return a count of the length. Say the string is 'abc', count will be 3.

The string has 3 chars myString[0], mystring[1] and ystring[2]. Note that there is no [3] character..

Reversing in place is tricky.

```
void reverser(char myString[])
{
    int count = findSize(myString);
    char *strPtr = myString
    char *endPtr = &myString[count - 1];
    strPtr = myString;

    for (int x = 0; x <= count / 2; x++)
    {
       char swap = *strPtr;
       strPtr[x] = *endPtr;
       *endPtr = swap;
       endPtr--;
    }
}
```

Disclaimer - I have not tested this code.

Comment: Tried the code, '!H!!!!!orld!' instead of reversed array...not quite sure how that happened

Comment: You need to decrement endPtr each loop. --endPtr; after `*endPtr = swap;`

Answer (score 0):

```
count = findSize(myString, count);
```

since findSize returns count you need count to equal the value it returns.

```
void reverser(char myString[])
{
int count = findSize(myString);
char *endPtr;
endPtr =& myString[count-1];
char *temp = new char[count];

for (int x = 0; x < count; x++)
{
     temp[x] = *endPtr;//this assgins the last letter of myString to the first element of temp 
     endPtr--;//decrement so endPtr points to myString[count - 1];
}
//now transfer
for(int x = 0; x < count; x++){
    myString[x] = temp[x];
}
delete [] temp;
}
```

Comment: code won't run. char temp messes up
Line 43: Error expression must have a constant value 
Line 43: Error C2131 expression did not evaluate to a constant 
Line 47: Error C3863 array type 'char [count]' is not assignable

Comment: created completely new program, ported over the code, same errors. 
The errors occur at the line with char temp[count + 1]; and again at temp[x] = *endPtr;

Comment: @jonthie instead of char temp[count +1] try putting char temp[13

Comment: that works! but I can't use that as that would be a 'magic number' and therefore against the style guide I must follow

Comment: `char temp[count];` isn't legal c++. That will not compile in Visual Studio.

Comment: variable length arrays

Comment: I would need to define another int as 'count+1' and then cast that into a constant probably

Comment: make int count const in the parameter of reverser function

Comment: VLA is a non standard extension supported by gcc not by msvc

Comment: also count is wrong, you should pass in count - 1. If the string has 3 chars the last one is [2] not [3]

Comment: @pm100 in this case count is returning 12 not 13 since strlen(myString) is equal to 12 strlen does not count null char

Comment: no. Defining another int as count+1 and then defining a const int as the first int does not work. putting const outside function also doesn't work as it is a 'non-numerical function'

Comment: i am aware that strlen doesnt count the null. I am also aware the c indexes start at 0, not 1. So a string of length one has a first char index of [0]

Comment: well the only solution I have for this is a dynamic array

Comment: wouldn't it work better if a loop was used instead inside the reverser() function instead of calling findSize()? supposed to have a pointer at start and another at end that swap, then move to second and second to last and swap etc.

Comment: @jonthie Yes that is what pm100 did and He was right about the count part I am sorry.

Comment: it works, but I hit a snag. the following must be true: "You must reverse the characters in-line, that is, you cannot use another array while you do this work. The function must be written so that it uses pointers only. No square brackets may be used inside of the function. "...I REALLY hate this program

Comment: @jonthie okay I edited pm100's code it should work now I hope he accepts the edit

Comment: @jonthie since he's not accepting the edit [here](http://cpp.sh/9jvws) go down to the reverser function

Comment: @jonthie you still would benefit deeply if you learn to effectively use your debugger. Even after 25+ years of c++ development (over 1 million lines of code) I still use the debugger nearly every day.